# How to compile tramp3d-v4

Tags: c++, gcc

I failed to compile the [tramp3d-v4.cpp](https://users.suse.com/~rguenther/tramp3d/) benchmark.

I have tried to use gcc-4.8, gcc-8, clang-1100.0.20.17 and also "-fpermissive". But it seems that it isn't the version problem.

```
gcc -fpermissive tramp3d-v4
```

and out put lots of error message.

I know that I can run this benchmark following [this](https://llvm.org/docs/TestSuiteGuide.html).

But I want to test the compilation time of compiling this cpp **ALONE**.

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing would be: why aren't you using g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: That solve it. sorry for the stupid question.
Thank you.